# Always show the widget title in a wordpress widget

Tags: widgets

I'm using the default category widget to show my category list in sidebar.

The problem is when I select some category to visit the corresponding category page [ex: football], the widget title [which is: My Category] disappears & shows the category title there [in this case: football]. I don't want that.

I want my widget to always show the widget title whether I select a category or not. I don't know if I explained it correctly or not!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not native behavior of it.

If you check the source of `WP_Widget_Categories`

```
$title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty( $instance['title'] ) ? __( 'Categories' ) : $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base );
```

The title comes exclusively from the value saved in instance (or default if not). There is no logic to tie it in with current context.

Something is changing that behavior, some possibilities that come to mind:

- you might have something override native widget
- some code might be using `widget_title`, possibly incorrectly, to override
- some JS code on front end might be changing title

Comment: this is the url: http://www.imransdesign.com/app/category/chicken/
can you check. see instead of showing category, it is showing chicken (3), the category title.

Comment: That's not actual title of the widget. The widget title seems to be present in source of the page, but not visible. Looks like a problem with theme styling or markup to me.

Comment: hummm got it... it was modified, thanks for pointing out!